# CDateTimeCtrl does not display time on Windows 10 RS2 (Build 1703)

Tags: time, fonts, mfc

I have created a dialog in **MFC** and used `CDateTimeCtrl` to show/set the time. Till **Windows 10 Build 10240** it was showing proper time but once you take latest updates of Windows, `CDateTimeCtrl` displays blank values.

The font used is "MS Shell Dlg".

My question is why `CDateTimeCtrl` shows blank value on Windows 10 RS2 (Build 1703), even though time is set. Is font "MS Shell Dlg" not supported on Windows 10 or is there any other reason?

Following is the code:

```
SYSTEMTIME systime;
long lStyle;
CFont Fontvar;
CDateTimeCtrl m_DateTimeCtrl

GetLocalTime(&systime);

lStyle = ::GetWindowLong(m_DateTimeCtrl.m_hWnd, GWL_STYLE);

lStyle |= DTS_TIMEFORMAT;

::SetWindowLong(m_DateTimeCtrl.m_hWnd, GWL_STYLE, lStyle);

Fontvar.CreatePointFont(10, _T("MS Shell Dlg"));

m_DateTimeCtrl.SetFont(&Fontvar);

m_DateTimeCtrl.SetFormat(_T("HH:mm:ss"));

m_DateTimeCtrl.SetTime(&systime);
```

Comment: Even if this appears to be obvious to yourself, it isn't to me: What is your question?

Comment: My question is why CDateTimeCtr shows blank value on Windows 10 RS2, even though time is set. Is font "MS Shell Dlg" not supported on Windows 10 or is there any other reason?

Comment: @Mrunal **MS Shell Dlg** is supported as far as I am aware. It is actually a font mapping to another font. The date time control functions on Windows 10. Have you considered providing more information like screen shots and appropriate code? Think about what you might need in order to answer someone's question. :)

Comment: In the above code if font is not set to CDateTimeCtrl then time is properly displayed in the control, however if font is set then CDateTimeCtrl do not display anything. Any idea to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Ah I saw this at CodeProject and as it may be as I suspected now seeing the code.

CFont Fontvar; must remain valid >>> for the lifetime <<< of CDateTimeCtrl m_DateTimeCtrl it isn't clear from the code that is true.

CFont Fontvar; is valid when you create m_DateTimeCtrl but we don't know if that code is just in some function and thus CFont Fontvar; is on the local stack and about to disappear.

It is also your responsibility to delete that font.

**Update:** Ok I take it back they have indeed broken MFC. You can't use setfont on the CDateTimeCtrl with any font not just that one. The only solution is go around MFC and use the windows API directly.

```
LOGFONT lf;
// clear out structure
memset(&lf, 0, sizeof(LOGFONT));
// request a 12-pixel-height font
lf.lfHeight = 12;
// request a face name "MS Shell Dlg"
_tcsncpy_s(lf.lfFaceName, LF_FACESIZE, _T("MS Shell Dlg"), _tcslen(_T("MS Shell Dlg")));
// create the font
HFONT hfont = ::CreateFontIndirect(&lf);

// Send the WM_SETFONT message to the date time control
m_dateTimeCtrl.SendMessage(WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hfont, 1);
```

Comment: It seems like KB4022725 (June 13, 2017) addressed this issue -- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4022725/windows-10-update-kb4022725.